# Android-how to show the videos in grid view using video url string

Tags: android

I have a url string in arraylist. how to display the url of video in gridview and on click the grid plays in next screen. how to implement this? any one guide me..

Comment: Have you tried any thing yet?

Comment: yes,I have crate a thumbnail  but i cannot add the thumbnail to ArrayAdapter                                          ArrayList<String> video = new ArrayList<String>();

Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( "drishtiq_yoga/uploads/videos/roja_1.3gp", MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Bitmap>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, thumbnail);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

I have a database which contains list of image and video path. This works fine for me

```
public class GridGallery extends Activity
{

    ArrayList<String>list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_gallery);
        DataModel dbModel = new DataModel(this);
        list = dbModel.selectAll();

        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }


     /**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     */
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final Context context; 

        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return list.size();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView picturesView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);

                 if(list.get(position).contains(".jpg"))
                {
                     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(position)); //Creation of Thumbnail of image
                }
                else if(list.get(position).contains(".mp4"))
                {
                    bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(list.get(position), 0); //Creation of Thumbnail of video
                }
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            }
            else 
            {
                picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }
            return picturesView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you play the video afterwards, I am trying to do something similar to instagram...